# If he had been the boy, he would have said, "That is OK, I will do it."

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

If you change the first sentence into an indirect speech, which would be the correct sentence?

1 If he had been the boy, he would have said, "That is OK, I will do it."

2 If he had been the boy, he would have said that it is Ok and that he will do it.

3 If he had been the boy, he would have said that it was OK and that he would do it.

4 If he had been the boy, he would have said that it were OK and that he would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Of the choices, I would favor number 3. It and only it gets the tenses correct.  But this is a case where direct speech is in my view clearer and better than indirect, so I would prefer number 1 to any of the others, and probably to  any form using indirect speech.

If indirect speech is to be used, take advantage of its ability to simplify and summarize, so rewrite as something like:

> If he had been the boy, he would have agreed to do it.

If the exact detail of the speech matters, use direct speech.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for your kind help! Please allow me to ask more.
I read that Sequence of tenses does not apply to subjunctive sentences such as the following.

He said, "If I were a superman, I would help her."
He said that if he were a superman, he would help her.

However, the rule doesn't apply to changing the sentence like 1: If he had been the boy, he would have said, "That is OK, I will do it." ?

Comment: Please do not post thank-yous or other followups as answers. Instead use a comment or post a new question and link the previous one, if it is relevant. Please do upvote and/or accept helpful answers

Comment: Also, please clarify what you mean by "Sequence of tenses". Thank you.

Comment: "Sequence of tenses"  : Cf. Wikipedia   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses